# Enable HTML in wordpress email template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email

I have a small php snippet which sends an email to members when they join my Wordpress website.

However the snippet only sends plain text, I'm trying to workout what needs to be changed so the email message sends in HTML.

I have included the snippet below:

```
/**
* Modify the message sent to a user after being approved.
*
* @param $message The default message.
* @param $user The user who will receive the message.
* @return string the updated message.
*/
function my_custom_message( $message, $user ) {
$message = 'Custom message here';
return $message;
}
// add a new custom approval message
add_filter( 'new_user_approve_approve_user_message', 'my_custom_message' );

// add a new custom denial message
add_filter( 'new_user_approve_deny_user_message', 'my_custom_message' );
```

Any solution would be appreciated

Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried adding HTML to the content of `$message`?  Is it parsed as HTML or simply output as plain text?  If the latter we need more code context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add html in wp\_mail function wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562381/add-html-in-wp-mail-function-wordpress)

Comment: Hi, adding HTML to $message, it comes out as plain text.

Comment: Hi, I followed the instructions in the other thread you mentioned,  that worked, thankyou :)

Comment: I simply needed to add the following code snippet: add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '))